# boost asio - memory management for socket class

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I have an boost asio server application and I'm struggling with how to transmit created sockets (e.g. transmit accept socket to the protocol implementation classes that will read/write data down the road)

For example if I make them being transmitted by shared_ptr to different classes that read/write to them it works out. My server has an io_service.run() before exiting the main program and all async operations done on those sockets are performed in there.

**EDIT** I found out that the problem was not the way I was transmitting socket class. It is possible to keep ownership of these in a class and passing reference down the road. In my case one of the connection classes were being destroyed before async operation handler finished their work.

Comment: There is quite a good video tutorial about object lifetimes (and managing them) made by asio creator at: [Thinking Asynchronously: Designing Applications with Boost Asio](http://blip.tv/boostcon/thinking-asynchronously-designing-applications-with-boost-asio-5250947)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question actually has nothing to do specifically with asio and could be genericized to *"How should I transfer ownership of allocated objects?"*.

And my answer would be: Use `std::unique_ptr`
(...for C++11)

If the receiver of the `unique_ptr` wants to use a different ownership idiom (like `shared_ptr`) it's easy to release from the `unique_ptr` and turn it into a `shared_ptr`. The opposite isn't true. This way, there is no time when your pointer is raw and could be leaked.

Comment: I find out as you said that the problems were in other places just that when I used shared_ptr they were disguised.

Comment: Handling the lifetime of different asio objects has to be careful though because when using async functions things gets more complicated.

Comment: accepted as answer because it pointed out that it was not specific to asio the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I use a shared pointer to store the data and pass it to the asio handler.  This is a UDP receive example but the concept is the same for transmit too.  (warning this is written from memory and un-compiled)

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t>          DATA_BUF_T;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<DATA_BUF_T> DATA_BUF_PTR_T;

void start_reading ()
{
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint (localAddr, usPort);

    m_socket.open (listen_endpoint.protocol());
    m_socket.bind (listen_endpoint);

    // create buffer to store received data
    DATA_BUF_PTR_T db (new DATA_BUF_T (max_length));

    m_socket.async_receive_from (
    boost::asio::buffer (*db, max_length), m_Status.peer,
    boost::bind (&handle_receive_from, this,
        db,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
    );

}


void handle_receive_from (DATA_BUF_PTR_T db,
                          const boost::system::error_code &error, 
                          size_t bytes_recvd)
{
    if (error)
    {
    return ;
    }

    // read data from db

}
```